# query don't work in node but work in postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

Node version - 8.9.4
pg module version - 7.4.3

this query

```
UPDATE test.new_orders
SET properties = properties || '{"statusid":1,"updatedAt":"2018-5-24 14:51:43"}'
WHERE to_timestamp((properties ->> 'updatedAt'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US') <= now() - INTERVAL '20 seconds'
AND properties ->> 'partitionid' = '6';
```

in node gives `

```
    Result {
    command: 'UPDATE',
    rowCount: 0,
    oid: null,        rows: [],        fields: [],
    _parsers: [],        RowCtor: null,        rowAsArray: false,
    _getTypeParser: [Function: bound ] }
```

but in postgres it always updates 3 rows.
What's the point?
How deal with this?

P.S.
This is my method

```
      getUpdatableOrdersAndUpdateStatuses(partitionid,orderProperties,interval) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let query = `UPDATE test.new_orders
                        SET properties = properties || '${orderProperties}'
                     WHERE to_timestamp((properties ->> 'updatedAt'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US') <= now() - INTERVAL '${interval}'
                     AND properties ->> 'partitionid' = '${partitionid}';`;
                     // test query = 'select * from test.new_orders'
                     console.log(query);         
        SQL.query(query, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return reject(err);
            }
            console.log(res);
            return resolve(true);
        })
    });
}
```

test query(select * from test.new_orders) gives normal result

also data

```
orderid properties

5281    {"tarifid": "1", "statusid": 1, "createdAt": "2018-05-24T13:40:57.544955", "updatedAt": "2018-5-24 14:46:49", "partitionid": "6"}

15  {"tarifid": "1", "statusid": 1, "createdAt": "2018-05-24T14:38:57.609023", "updatedAt": "2018-5-24 14:46:49", "partitionid": "6"}

152 {"tarifid": "1", "statusid": 1, "createdAt": "2018-05-24T14:39:11.655951", "updatedAt": "2018-5-24 14:46:49", "partitionid": "6"}
```

awesome!!! Forgot to addd AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Yerevan'

Comment: postgres `8.9.4` and json?.. how did you do that? (unless you have your own `->>` operator of course)

Comment: My bet is configuration issue: maybe you're talking to different databases. Or your first query is executed in the same (uncommitted) transaction where data is inserted, and your Node code (different connection) does not see it yet due to isolation.

Comment: data is inserted and this is no process inserting or editing data

Comment: Vao Tsun : query is copied from console,is there any problem executing this query in node 8.9.4?

Comment: Perhaps one of the values you inject result in a different query.